# Python/Flask - ANSI codes are now appearing in console

Tags: python, flask, console

I've been putting my Google Fu to work over the last couple of days to try to get some info but I'm coming up short.

I've got a Python/Flask web application up and running, and am a few commits in by this point. The purpose of it isn't too important, but since picking it up (last time used was in October '19) I've noticed that the normal console output (showing the different page requests as you click through the application) has started to a series of characters before and after each request (see photo).

[image]

I had no idea what these were originally but they didn't seem to affect my application in any way, but it's been grating on me ever since. I've since found out that these are ANSI codes and are used to format the text output in the console (please correct me if I'm wrong!)
These were definitely not there previously and I'd really like to understand where these came from and, either suppress them or find a way to work with them such that they work, rather than just showing the characters.

edit: This is in Windows 10 (64 bit) and using the standard Windows CMD console. I don't believe that there was an update to this, but there could have been one pushed that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is there a chance you were running using a different terminal before, e.g. maybe one built into your IDE? Windows doesn't have good support for these codes, but you may have been using a terminal that understood (and therefore didn't display) them.

Comment: I'll update the main post but the computer didn't change (Windows 10, 64bit) and the terminal I don't _think_ changed. I use the standard Windows console with the Git integration.

I tried MinTTY but really didn't like it (maybe I should try) so stuck with Windows CMD

Comment: "I tried MinTTY"—MinTTY almost certainly _does_ understand ANSI codes. Look for colour-coded output instead of those visible codes.

Comment: Yeah, it was a while ago that I tried it... Maybe I just need to give it another try.

I was hoping that I'd be able to find out what changed, or how to deal with these as is though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that _nothing_ changed, other than your terminal. In any case, you may be able to change this behaviour by [configuring Flask's logging](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/).

Comment: @Chris, thanks, I had a look through but couldn't see anything. I'll try with MinTTY but will have a fiddle around with the Windows console in the meantime and see what I can sort out.

I DON'T LIKE CHANGE hehe. Makes me worry that I did something...

Thanks!